# C#: Unable to Bypass Cache (WebClient)

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.BypassCache);
```

Why is this code above not actually preventing sites from being cached through the .Net Web Client?

Comment: How are you seeing that they are being cached? This just adds a header to the request, it doesn't control what the server actually sends.

Answer (score 0):

```
string xmlUrl = "http://myserver.com/xmlfile.xml";

WebClient client = new WebClient();

// prevent file caching by windows
client.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(
System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore
);

// read content of file
Stream rssStream = client.OpenRead(xmlUrl);
```

Use No Cache No Store.

**Edit**: If it doesn't work then try with webrequest/webresponse:

```
 WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
        // Define a cache policy for this request only. 
        HttpRequestCachePolicy noCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        request.CachePolicy = noCachePolicy;
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: I have tried NoCacheNoStore as well as BypassCache and they both do not work.